# ODI 12c DB to XML

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to map oracle db to an XML file and have come to a blocker.Would appreciate any help.My xml file has the following structure

```
<Root>
     <Import>
           <Add-Item1>
           .
           .
           <Add-Item n></Add-Item n>
    </Import>
```

Odi 12c xml driver generates a ParentElementFK CurrentElementPK and CurrentElementOrder,corresponding to every tag that is there in xml.
My issue is in spite of scouring oracle forums i have not found a good definition of what data we need to populate in these ODI generated columns. Are these only for maintaining the hierarchical relationship?if so,wouldn't they be populated automatically on reverse engineering?.suppose the data that i would fill in this xml structure would be of an item with properties-brand,description item id(child tags under ) .Do these generated columns play any role in the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple things and found the answer myself . here is what i understood. Suppose you have Import complex type and Add-Item complexType . It will generate two datastores in model one for Import and one for Add-Item. First populate the primary key of the Import Complex type. Then you will see IMport FK in the Add-item complex type populate this value with the same value as you populated above that works . All other order and can be left optional if you don't need any particular order of these